# What is the purple stuff on Doflamingo's strings?

Tags: one-piece

In the latest episode, we see a pure purple color at the tips of the string attack. I've never seen this before. What is it?

[image: At the tip]

I didn't think it was Busō-shoku no Haki, because that's black:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's Busō-shoku no Haki (should be black but Toei since Punk Hazzard have colored the CoA with that color).

Comment: Huh? But Toei colors it black (see Chinjao's head during it, etc)

Comment: white + black = lighter black maybe

Answer (score 1):

It's Busō-shoku no Haki. Most Busō-shokus are black because they are on something that's not light colored (skin or Doflamingo's strings).
The only exceptions I've seen are Luffy and Chinjao. Doffy's shoe is Busō-shoku'd so it's black, Vergo's staff is Busō-shoku'd so it's black, Vergo's skin is Busō-shoku'd so it's purple.
It may be that the color underneath chooses whether it's purple or black. It may even just be the concentration of Haki.

Answer (score 0):

For one it could be blood. Second, it can be armament haki since it varies from person to person. Just like how Vergo's was purple in color and Luffy's is black. Since we don't know much about them, I think it's safe to assume that the color matches the person's power or personality.